# Is it implied that the Joker and The Penguin killed their own henchmen?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, batman-the-animated-series

In *Batman: The Animated Series* episodes [The Man Who Killed Batman](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/The_Man_Who_Killed_Batman) and [The Mechanic](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/The_Mechanic), both the villains seem to kill their own henchmen off screen.

From [The Man Who Killed Batman](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0519636/quotes/qt0356824):

> The Joker: You know, there's just one thing bothering me about your story, Sidney. No body. No Batus delecti, if you will. We need to pull a job tonight to be sure.
>
> Murphy: Be sure of what, boss?
>
> The Joker: [doing a double-take at Murphy] Why that old Batsy's bought
> the cave, of course. And one more thing, Murphy... don't ask stupid
> questions.
>
> [Joker pushes Murphy into the midst of Harley Quinn's two hyenas, who
> claw off his shirt and lick him silly]
>
> Harley Quinn: I'll get the mop.

I always thought Harley's suggestion of getting the mop meant that the hyenas would kill him, and she would have to clean it up.

In The Mechanic, The Penguin leads one of his men into a whirlpool and his screams are heard in the background.

**Did they actually kill their henchmen in these scenes?**

Comment: I feel like the mop reference was just implying that Murphy had urinated out of fear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases the show implies punishment not necessarily death while death is a possible inference it is not the only one.

For what its worth Joker is explicitly shown shooting a henchman in the the 1989 Batman movie.

Comment: I always thought the scream of the guy entering the whirlpool was disturbing.

Comment: In Mystery Men the villain says something like, as he kills his own men, "See, I kill my own men!" -- the mark of the bad guys is that they don't even like/are not loyal to each other. "No honor among thieves" is an aphorism related to this.

Comment: Joker also shot his own guy at the end of the bank robbery in The Dark Knight (film). In the Batman video games, all of the main villains show no remorse for killing their own men to further along their agenda. Some super villains even team up with each other only to turn on each other later when the time is right to double cross them.